# When does React re-render the parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently learning React, and trying to get a sense of how components re-render. I have this parent component which renders three items. Each item just renders an `<li>`

```js
function App() {
  console.log("Parent Rerendered");
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <Item1 />
        <Item2 />
        <Item3 />
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Item2 is a bit different because it also renders an "x" that will un-render the component when it's clicked:

```js
function Item2() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

  const makeInvisible = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  };

  console.log("Item 2 Rerendered");

  return visible ? (
    <div>
      <li>
        Second Item <span onClick={makeInvisible}>X</span>
      </li>
    </div>
  ) : null;
}
```

When I test this in my browser and click the "x", I can see from the console that `Item2` gets re-rendered. However, none of the other components get re-rendered including the parent component. However the parent component does change, so how does this happen without re-rendering it.

If that's a bit confusing, here's an illustration of the initial state, my expectations, and reality. What am I misunderstanding about how React re-renders components?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of clicking onto `<Item2 />` go to the Dev-tools -> Explorer -> select the Element and press delete. The view will also change, the gap will close, without react being involved at all.

React is responsible to update the DOM, the **layout** is done by the browser. So when `<Item2 />` decides it wants to be rendered as `null` instead of a `div>li` *(??? invalid markup )* and therefore removes the respective DOM-nodes, the browser will update the layout.

And the parent component has nothing to do with all that.

Answer (score 2):

A component rerenders when it sets state, or when its parent rerenders<sup>1</sup>. `App` has no state and no parent, so it will never rerender. It doesn't need to though. React saves the virtual DOM from the previous render, so it still knows that `App` is supposed to be a `div` surrounding a `ul` surrounding an `Item1`, `Item2`, and `Item3`. If the `Item2` rerenders, and returns a null instead of a div, react will update the part of the real DOM that the `Item2` is responsible for, by removing the div. The rest of the page remains intact

<sup>1) or if a context it consumes changes, or in a class component when you call forceUpdate. But for most cases, it's just state and parent that matter.</sup>